# How to add second hand in analog clock widget in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, widget, clock

I am making Analog clock widget in android, how to add second hand in analog clock widget which moves at every 1 seconds with system time?, I used AnalogClock class but its doesn't provide second hand attribute to add. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Starting SDK 31 (Android 12) you can use xml atribute `android:hand_second` for set a second hand.
You have to create a drawable for it. I recommend use `vector` resource.

[image]